# Visual Studio 2008 takes too long to build Windows Forms App solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I looked everywhere on the internet and this web site and found nothing that would help me so I resorted to make my own post.

I have a VS 2008 solution comprising of 6 projects: 1 Windows Forms App, 1 Windows Service, 4 DLLs. They are built in VB.

When I try to build one of the projects, or all of them, it says "Build started..." at the bottom of the IDE but the IDE appears to be frozen...can't click anything on it...and it stays like this for about 30 minutes. After that, it "unfreezes" and I can continue working with it.  I am trying to find out what is the cause for this behavior, how can I correct it? Anything that can help.

FYI - I am building/running from the IDE...not building from command prompt. Also, there are some third-party DLLs that are referenced but not registered. However, I don't think this is the problem because the compiler should only report the warning (like it is actually doing) and go on with the build... I don't see why it would freeze because of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give some details about your configuration (hardware, OS, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Virus Scanner or some other disk monitoring service running?  I would try and disable all of those first to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a virus scanner, but it is not causing any problems. Other coworkers have the same antivirus software and using VS2008 and they don't have this kind of problems.

Comment: Typically, if your coworkers are not experiencing similar behavior, then something environmental is likely going on.  I would start disabling things in your environment that may be causing a problem regardless of their impact on your colleagues machines.  Turn off things in Visual Studio first (Resharper, DevEx Experience, or anything similar) then focus on things outside (virus scanners, altiris, etc.)  Disable each item one at a time, test, reenable if it's not the culprit until you find the cause.  It's most likely not at all code related.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't got a perfect answer from last 3 years, My VS2010 Solution have 2 projects, One is my application and 2nd is my Installer Project, My solution was taking 10 minutes to build, I added output window to layout, and I checked my application project was building in couple of seconds, But it was installer project that was taking too much time, So I temporary removed that Installer project, and everything was working fine.